# Is there any method to display male and female Gender name alone in HashMap/HashTable in java?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable, hashset

My requirement is (by using HashMap/HashTable/HashSet) Student Roll no as Key and Student name and Gender are as values of that key.
Could maintain in ArrayList and need to print Female Gender student name alone and Male name alone.

Comment: Names should never be used in keys. They are not unique. Check almost any list of people over 100, and there will probably be duplicates. Try email address or an auto-generated key.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having 2 Tables, 1 for each gender as the most simple solution. Then you don't have to filter out one gender for every search.